# Changing how argument lists are indented in JavaScript

Tags: indentation, javascript

Right now, my argument lists are indented by `js-mode` like this:

```
some_long_function_name( one_argument,
                         another_argument );
```

How can I get them to look like this:

```
some_long_function_name( one_argument,
    another_argument );
```

(My `c-basic-offset` is already set to 4.)

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work for you, this one might help: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29975/4085

Comment: @ColinFraizer Yep, looked at that. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Have you looked at [`js2-mode`](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode)? It's significantly more flexible than the built-in `js-mode`. A quick grep reveals the user option `js2-bounce-indent-p` may be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Support for this was [recently added](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=9ac7dccc51ee834b06cdabf6a5746eb375f984f0) in the Emacs development tree, in response to the [bug#27503 feature request](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=27503), which in turn was inspired by [a duplicate of this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29973/15748).

The user option which controls this behaviour is `js-indent-align-list-continuation`, and it affects all list-like structures:

> `js-indent-align-list-continuation` is a variable defined in `js.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Align continuation of non-empty `([{` lines in `js-mode`.

So, for the desired effect:

```el
(setq-default js-indent-align-list-continuation nil)
```

In order to avail of this option, however, you will need to either:

- compile and install the latest Emacs;
- wait for Emacs 26 to be released; or
- place a patched version of `js.el` in your `load-path`.

Alternatively, you can override the current behaviour to match the future behaviour as per [Colin Fraizer's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29975/15748) to the aforementioned duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you're looking for, but you can get `another_argument` to be where you want by putting a newline before `one_argument`:

```
some_long_function_name( 
    one_argument,
    another_argument
);
```